# "Unable to sign in from this country" error message when trying to send email via Gmail via C# or browser

Tags: c#, dns, gmail

Our web server will no longer send email via our gmail account.

When trying to diagnose the problem we've noticed that when logging into the browser based gmail interface we get this message:

Unable to sign in from this country

You appear to be signing in from a country where Google Apps accounts are not supported

The error message from the C# code is:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Everything has been working absolutely fine without an error for 2 years and then suddenly stopped on the 13th November.

We have performed a ipconfig /flushdns and then a tracert - all the IPs are UK/US based and the server in located in England.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have remote server access ? then go to server via remote desktop and login to gmail once.